# How to test a library in solidity with Chai

Tags: mocha.js, solidity, chai

What is the best method to test a library contract with Chai/Mocha in solidity using hardhat?
I'm getting:

> Types containing (nested) mappings can only be parameters or return
> variables of internal or library functions.

When I try to make the library a contract for testing

Answer (score 1):

you can use [hardhat](https://hardhat.org/) or [truffle](https://trufflesuite.com/)
in with you can use mocha or chai for test

Answer (score 0):

Please create a mock contract that imports the library and uses the functions.
Then you can write tests for the contract.